# Scroll to top of page on element hide with Onsen UI

Tags: jquery, onsen-ui

I have the following page:

```
<ons-template id="login.html">
<ons-page id="login-page">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Register</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <div class="content" style="text-align: center">

    <div id="startCodeRegistration">
      <!-- long form with many fields -->
    </div>

    <div id="endCodeRegistration" style="display:none;">
      <!-- just a success message -->
      <p>Registration Complete!</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

In my success handler I have:

```
$( '#startCodeRegistration' ).hide();
$( '#endCodeRegistration' ).show();
```

Everything is working except I don't see the success message because the page is still scrolled down because the user had to scroll to the bottom of the page to submit the form. Is there any way to scroll the page to the top?

I tried:

```
document.getElementById('endCodeRegistration').scrollIntoView();
```

I also tried:

```
document.querySelector('#endCodeRegistration').scrollTop = 0;
```

Neither worked. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any elements with ID startCodeRegistration or endCodeRegistration in your html??!!

Comment: Sorry. Fixed element ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `style="position: fixed;"` to endCodeRegistration.
This should make it so that its always over everything